# Delete every duplicate from each word alone in a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, duplicates

I have to write a code that deletes every character that gets repeated in a single word in a string.
If it gets repeated in other words, that's irrelevant.
I have to use arrays and strings only (no hashs, sb.append, other functions..)

Example:

> input = recommend that profession | output = rcond ha prfein.

I have to delete the duplicates and the letter itself (that gets repeated in the same word).
Any ideas? help?

Answer (score 1):

Split the string in word using the string.split method. Using the space character for splitting up the string, you will get an array of pieces of that string, for each element of the array save the length of the word and try to iterate with a for each of every character in the word with a counter each time that tells if it’s repeated and removes that character

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String str = "recommend that profession";
    String output ="";
    // Separating word from string
    String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
    for(int i=0;i<splited.length;i++){
        //removing repeated char and its original from each word 
        String word = splited[i];
        for(int j = 0;j<word.length();j++){
            char c = word.charAt(j);
            for(int k =j+1;k<word.length();k++){
                char d  = word.charAt(k);
                String deleted = String.valueOf(d);
                // Checking if the characters are repeated
                if(c==d){
                    word = word.replaceAll(deleted,"");
                }
            }
        }
        // Concatenating the main string 
        output+=word+" "; 
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```